# Use sed to grab a string

Tags: regex, sed

I'm using curl to get the html from a site then I just need a specific string which is between 'standards.xml?revision=' and '&amp'. I'm using sed to do this but I can't seem to get the regex right and needed some help.

```
curl website.com | sed -r 's|.*standards\.xml\?revision=([0-9]+).*|\1|'
```

The output I'm getting is the full html--any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you should use grep...

Comment: How would I use grep for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there. Try using `-n` option with `sed` not to print unmatched data and add `p` modifier to `s|||` to print replace string

```
curl website.com | sed -n -r 's|.*standards\.xml\?revision=([0-9]+).*|\1|p'
```

Comment: @Konnor Welcome! It seems you're new to this site. If any ans is working for you, consider accepting that ans by clicking on hollow green tick mark besides ans. P.S. I noticed you haven't accepted any of your 3 answers.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `grep -oP` (PCRE option):

```
grep -oP 'standards\.xml\?revision=\K[0-9]+'
```

`\K` resets the matched text hence only later part `[0-9]+` is returned.

Answer (score 1):

```
curl website.com | sed -n '/xml/ {s|.*standards\.xml\?revision=([^&]+).*|\1|p;q;}'
```

From previous sed [0-9]+ is only if number occur maybe a [^&]+ is more appropriate. 
Very good to use the ' and | to avoid problem with \ so I pick it :-)