# How to use sed to grab regular expression

Tags: regex, bash, sed, osx-yosemite

I'd like to grab the digits in a string like so :

```
 "sample_2341-43-11.txt"   to   2341-43-11
```

And so I tried the following command:

```
echo "sample_2341-43-11.txt" | sed -n -r 's|[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}|\1|p'
```

I saw this answer, which is where I got the idea.
[Use sed to grab a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19689482/use-sed-to-grab-a-string), but it doesn't work on my machine:

- it gives an error "illegal option `-r`".
- it doesn't like the `\1`, either.

I'm using sed on MacOSX yosemite.

Is this the easiest way to extract that information from the file name?

Comment: you do not need the \1 for the expression you are looking for

Comment: -r is only for GNU sed (the one that comes with bash) isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set your grouping and match the rest of the line to remove it with the group.   Also the - does not need to be escaped.   And the -n will inhibit the output (It just returns exit level for script conditionals).

```
echo "sample_2341-43-11.txt" | sed -r 's/^.*([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}).*$/\1/'
```

Comment: It will not work on MacOSX yosemite! see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12178924/os-x-sed-e-doesnt-accept-extended-regular-expressions

Answer (score 2):

Enhanced regular expressions are [not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12178924/os-x-sed-e-doesnt-accept-extended-regular-expressions) in the Mac version of sed.

You can use `grep` instead:

```
echo "sample_2341-43-11.txt" | grep -Eo "((\d+|-)+)"
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2341-43-11
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "one1sample_2341-43-11.txt" \
 | sed 's/[^[:digit:]-]\{1,\}/ /g;s/ \{1,\}/ /g;s/^ //;s/ $//'

1 2341-43-11
```

- Extract all numbers(digit) completed with `-` (thus allow here `--12` but can be easily treated)
- posix compliant
- all number of the line are on same line (if several) separate by a space character (could be changed to new line if wanted)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this ways also

```
sed 's/[^_]\+_\([^.]\+\).*/\1/' <<< sample_2341-43-11.txt
```

**OutPut:**

```
2341-43-11
```

**Explanation:**

```
[^_]\+       - Match the content untile _ ( sample_)
\([^.]\+\)   - Match the content until . and capture the pattern (2341-43-11)
.*           - Discard remaining character (.txt)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can go with what the poster above said. Well, making use of this

pattern "\d+-\d+-\d+"   would match what you are looking for. See demo here

https://regex101.com/r/kO2cZ1/3

Comment: I believe the \1 was a reference to his matching group.